# Use Value in Column as Upper Limit of Summation to Create a New Column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a new column in an R data.table that sums from 1 to the value in a different column. Here's an example:

| x (existing column) | y (new column) |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 |

In the first row of the table we get y by summing 1 through 2 (1+2=3), in the second we sum 1 through 3 (1+2+3=6), etc. In the real problem the values in x can be any integer (i.e. they're not in order and not predictable).

I've tried a few different things, starting with the very naive approach:
`dt[,y:=sum(c(1:x))]` which, unsurprisingly, gives warnings about only using some elements of x, since it's (I believe) trying to use x as a column instead of using the variable in each row of x. I tried using `lapply` to work on each row, but I can't get that to work either.

The obvious solution, which I've implemented for now, is to loop through each row, in which case the problem is trivial. However, I feel like there must be a more streamlined data.table solution somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is effectively `1:(2:5)` while `:` is expecting a single number on each side (so it just takes the first; 2).

Here are alternatives that should work:

```
dt[, y := sapply(x, \(y) sum(1:y))]


dt[, y := (x*(x+1L)) %/% 2L]
```

Reproducible data:

```
dt <- data.table(x = 2L:5L)
```

Comment: Thanks @s_baldur, I appreciate the answer. I'm not familiar with the notation in the solution. Would you be able to explain it or point me towards some documentation explaining it. I haven't had any luck finding any.